# Generating Number using JSTL in JSP Page

Tags: java, jsp, jstl

I want to generate Age in Dropdown List in JSP page

```
<select name="cboAge" id="cboAge">
<%  
  for(int i=20;i<50;i++)
 { %>     
   <option value="<%= i%>"><%= i%></option>
 <% } %>  
</select>
```

Which Tag would be appropriate if I choose from jstl tag Library since the above method is highly discouraged one

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use [JSTL](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/jstl/info) [`<c:forEach>`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/jstl/1.1/docs/tlddocs/c/forEach.html).

```html
<c:forEach begin="20" end="49" var="i">
    <option value="${i}">${i}</option>
</c:forEach>
```

Note that `end` is inclusive.

Comment: As always, you're faster than a bullet

Answer (score -1):

Use jquery for this

```
</script><script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    var selectAge = $("#selectAge"), i;
    for ( i = 20; i < 50; i++) {
        $(selectAge).append("<option value='" + options[i] + "'>" + i + "</option>");
    }
});
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Using JSTL. Read the question more carefully.

Comment: jQuery is definitely awesome, but this answer makes really no utter sense :) http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/48195/138231 Use the right tool for the job.